# How do you assign a string value to a property in another class in Swift?

Tags: swift

I've got some swift code that looks like this:

```
class GeoRssItem
{
    var title = ""
    var description = ""
}
```

In another class I declare a variable of this as:

```
var currentGeoRssItem : GeoRssItem?    // The current item that we're processing
```

I allocate this member variable as:

```
        self.currentGeoRssItem = GeoRssItem();
```

then when I try to assign a property on the self.currentGeoRssItem Xcode auto completes to this:

```
        self.currentGeoRssItem.?.description = "test"
```

Which then fails with a build error as so:

```
"Expected member name following '.'"
```

How do I set this property? I've read the docs but they aren't very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question mark is in the wrong place. Should be:

```
self.currentGeoRssItem?.description = "test"
```

However you might get: `"Cannot assign to the result of this expression"`.
In that case you need to check for nil like this:

```
if let geoRssItem = self.currentGeoRssItem? {
    geoRssItem.description = "test"
}
```

Comment: Yup; “...you can use optional chaining to access a property on an optional value, and to check if that property access is successful. *You cannot, however, set a property’s value through optional chaining*.” — The Swift Programming Language, "Optional Chaining".

Answer (score 0):

If you want to assert that the value is non-nil, you can do:

```
self.currentGeoRssItem!.description = "test"
```

If you want the statement to be a no-op if the variable is nil, then

```
self.currentGeoRssItem?.description = "test"
```

Comment: The ! works, but using the ? results in the error "Cannot assign to the result of this expression"